# Kotlin table formatting

Tags: android, kotlin

This is my first Kotlin app, so please be gentle on me.
I am using a table to show my results, which vary in size, so I defined the table in the context and then added the rows and textviews for the cells dynamically. My problem is that if I then switch to show it as a graph and the use the back button, the table content and left side of the cell stays in the same place, but the cell widths all become the same size.
As this is my first post, I can't include a screen shot, but it ends up looking a bit like this:
Before

| 1234 | 12345 | 12456 | 1234567 |

After

| 123| | 1234|5 | 1234|56 | 1234|567

The pipe shows the left and right cell borders, the top and bottom match them (but I can't see how to show them).

The content XML contains the table layout within a scrollview

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/swimmerResultsOverallTime">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/scrollView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PresetEntryMeet" />
</ScrollView>
```

The code to populate each row is:

```
var headerRow = TableRow(thisContext)

var listLengthHeader = TextView(thisContext)
listLengthHeader.text = " Length "
listLengthHeader.textSize = 12F
listLengthHeader.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
listLengthHeader.setBackground(border)
headerRow.addView(listLengthHeader)
```

The block starting var listLengthHeader onwards is repeated for each cell and then followed by:

```
eventResultTable.addView(headerRow)
```

to add the row to the table. This is then all repeated for each row.

Comment: more important than a screenshot is to include actual code, your question is way too difficult to answer without adding more detail

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please include the code as formatted text into the question itself, not as a comment.